# Probability of event occurring twice in 3 days after not occurring in 1000 years

Tags: probability

Not being skilled in math at all, I'd like to ask the following:

Imagine an event happening 1000 years ago (ex. big meteorite falling on earth) and then never again until the last three days, in which the same event happened twice. What are the probabilities of that happening? (1 in x chances of happening)

Can someone help me?

Comment: If the event is so rare, we can use the poisson-distribution. But since the event happened only once, it is impossible to estimate the parameter $\lambda$ reasonably. The question can only be answered if we assume that the event happens once in 1000 years in long run, very speculative without further informations.

Comment: It depends on the actual event and how we model it.

Comment: Hm. Okay... lets say that before 1000 years ago the event happened every 10 years.

Comment: I'd say in that case that before you can apply mathematics to the problem, you must know something about the physical process involved.  Why did it stop?  Why did it resume?  A mathematical approach would introduce a specific model of the physical process, and without knowing more about it, we can't know what model to apply.

Comment: It would be like asking what the odds are of two siblings being born with two differently colored eyes, without knowing a darned thing anything about genetics.

Comment: Well, there is a British couple with two sets of twins, each one black and one white. I know nothing about their eye colour.

Comment: _IF_ you assume indepedence of the rare event happening in non-overlapping time intervals, and _if_ you assume a constant rate, then this can be modeled as a Poisson process. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Okay, people. Thanks. I'm assuming it's pretty much impossible to calculate the probabilities like this. (To clarify: I was asking it for a literature reference in a fiction novel.)

Answer (score 0):

If we just assume that the probability of such an event occurring in a randomly chosen year is ${1 \over 1000}$, and assume the probability is independent, and assume the entire event can take place within a day, then the probability that the event will occur on any randomly chosen day is ${1 \over 365000}$, as we convert years to days. Then, the probability that the event will *not* occur on any randomly chosen day is ${364999 \over 365000}$. Therefore the probability that the event will occur twice within the span of three days is ${1 \over 365000} \cdot{1 \over 365000}\cdot{364999 \over 365000} = {364999 \over 48627125000000000}$, $0.00000000075$%, or roughly $1$ in $133$ billion

*EDIT:* However I just saw your comment saying, before it happened $1000$ years ago, it happened every $10$ years. In that case, the answer is different. You have to take into account the dry spell of $1000$ years during which the event did not occur.
In which case, the probability the event will occur in a randomly chosen year is $1 \over 10$, and for a randomly chosen day it is $1 \over 3650$. Therefore the probability that the event will not occur for $1000$ years consecutively is $({3649 \over 3650})^{365000}$. Next we multiply that by ${3649 \over 3650} \cdot {1 \over 3650}^2$, the probability that the event will occur within the span of three days, and the answer is $2.75 \times 10^{-50}$%, or roughly $1$ in $3.6$ billion billion billion billion.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that this event happens twice in the next 72 hours is very low indeed. But if this event happens every thousand years, then it will happen eventually, and the chance that it happens again within the next 72 hours is low, but not incredibly low (about 1 in 100,000).

However, there are many possible events that happen once every thousand years. It is quite likely that *some* very unlikely event will happen eventually.